# Disable Java in LibreOffice

Tags: redhat, java, openoffice

I am working on deploying LibreOffice to RHEL7 workstations, and I need a way to disable LibreOffice's Java settings globally. I refer to `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice/Advanced -> "Use a Java runtime environment"`.

I need this option to be disabled for every user, and the user should not be able to re-enable it. I can turn off and disable many other settings in XML files under `/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/registry`, but I can't figure out the XML path for Java there.

I am aware that Java can be disabled by default for a particular user, using the `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/javasettings_Linux_X86_64.xml` file, but this obviously is not a global setting, and nor does it seem to be possible to stop the user from turning it back on.

Comment: [Cross posted from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657368/disable-java-in-libreoffice).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.